# Unable to build qt from the source (for the OpenCV)

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am trying to install OpenCV on my Windows 10 following [this](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html) guide. In order to install it with my own-build libraries, I need to build qt from the source. I downloaded the latest sources from the qt page (5.6.0, I didn't find any other sources availible), but after typing

```
configure -release -no-webkit -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-script -   no-scripttools
          -no-qt3support -no-multimedia -no-ltcg
```

In VS2013/VS2015 command promt, I got an error:

```
Unknown option -no-webkit
Unable to detect the platform from environment. Use -platform command line
argument or set the QMAKESPEC environment variable and run configure again.
```

I have an option just to make everything. But I have to specify the platform. I didn't find how to do it.

Can anyone give me a hint, how to install qt correctly? I have VS 2013 and 2015. I am going to use VS2013, since VS2015 is not supported by CUDA toolkit 7.5.

Thanks,

Mikhail

Update: I was able to begin the installation process by typing `configure -platform win32-msvc2013 -mp -release` (although I have win64), but after accepting the licence, I got an error: `execute: File or path was not found(nmake)`. Screenshot is attached[image]

Comment: Here's a [hack that enables CUDA with VS2015.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L4tpXtsjyVg) Its not perfect, but seems to be sort of functional. I wish NVidia would get an update out there...

Comment: Just in case you didn't get a notification, I've updated my answer to solve your latest problem. let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried with the MSVC2013 command prompt:

`configure -platform win32-msvc2013 -mp -release -no-webkit -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-script -no-scripttools -no-qt3support -no-multimedia -no-ltcg`

then type:

`nmake`

**Update:**

Also, before that, try adding the path to your Qt source code, with the bin folder, to the `PATH` variable of windows.

For instance, if your `PATH` variable is currently set to `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;` and your Qt source code is at `C:\dev\Qt-5.6\`
then set your `PATH` variable to `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;C:\dev\Qt-5.6;C:\dev\Qt-5.6\bin`

This website explains how to change the `PATH` variable on Windows, in case you're not familiar with it: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Then restart the MSVC2013 Command Prompt, or Windows. I believe that should help the compilation. Let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That helped, but now I encountered other problem. Please see update.

Comment: I've updated my answer, maybe that could solve the problem you're having with qmake. let me know.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:
`-skip qtwebkit`

> Excluding a Qt Submodule
>
> Configure's -skip option allows certain Qt submodules to be excluded from the Qt build. These submodules correspond to the Git submodules in the standard Qt 5 repository. Note that many packages contain multiple Qt modules. For example, to exclude Qt NFC and Qt Bluetooth from the Qt build, provide -skip qtconnectivity as the argument to configure.

Comment: Thanks, I found this as well. But this doesn't solve my problem